# how to specify a field which should not indexed?

Tags: elasticsearch

as mentioned in the title, I want to disable index a specified field in `elasticsearch`, for example, I have a fields named `@fileds` which contains three sub-fields like `name、age、salary`, now I do not want to index the field `@fields.age` in `elasticsearch`, how can I achieve that? I have tried to use  `include_in_all` parameters, but it doesn't work. `mapping` configuration like:

```
"mappings": {
    "fluentd": {
        "properties": {
            "@fields": {
                "properties": {
                    "age": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "include_in_all": false,
                                "index": "no"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I use this `mapping` configuration above, I can only see `@fields.age` in the index's mapping, `@fields.name` and `@fields.salary` should appear on the index's mapping not the `@fields.age`, how can this happen? any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the mapping file you send to ES include @fields.name and @fields.salary?  The one you supplied doesn't...why omit them?  Supplying the index: no param does indeed prevent the field from being indexed, but that simply means you cannot query on them, you will still see them in your result sets.

Comment: yep, we omit them